# Glob ignore pattern does not appear to be working with gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, glob

I have an AngularJS project with Karma-run Jasmine unit tests and am trying to use Gulp as my task automator. I have the test `spec` files alongside the other concept files as [prescribed by the JohnPapa Angular 1 style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y197).

I am trying to ignore the `*.spec.js` files in my application concatenation step using [glob's ignore option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#options) to prevent including the test code in the distributed app file but it's not working.

```
gulp.task('js:concat:application', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    our.js + 'app.js',
    our.js + '**/*.module.js',
    our.js + '**/*.js'
  ], { ignore: ['**/*.spec.js'] })
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(our.built.js));
});
```

I've tried `'*.spec.js'`, `'**/*.spec.js'`, and `'spec.js'`, and the same values but as the only value in an array as shown above.

[`gulp.src`'s documentation](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpsrcglobs-options#section-options) says that `node-glob`'s options (which includes the `ignore` option) are supported, but adding them how the documentation describes doesn't appear to be working. At this point, I'm not sure why it's not working.

Versions:

- gulp CLI: 1.2.2
- gulp Local version: 3.9.1
- node: 6.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude specific files in `gulp.src` by prepending an exclamation mark to the pattern as indicated in the [glob documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer).

```
gulp.task('js:concat:application', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    our.js + 'app.js',
    our.js + '**/*.module.js',
    our.js + '**/*.js',
    '!**/*.spec.js'])
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(our.built.js));
});
```